# Error squiggles in vscode are not working in React

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

[image]

I don't know what is the error with react in vscode.
after I create react app every thing works well, but sometimes when I install a npm package the error squiggles stop working.

As you see, I deleted the importing statement but no red lines appeared in the code.

Comment: Can you clarify what the exact problem you are facing. As far as I can see, the problem in the image indicates that you're using the `BrowserRouter` without importing it at the top.

Comment: Sure, I want vscode to show error squiggles when I miss something by showing red lines under undefined expressions such as BrowserRouter here, so here I intentionally didn't import it to show you the error I am facing.

Comment: I don't think they appear by default in VS Code. However, you can check whether ESLint is installed or not(https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint). it does the intended behavior you're asking for. Also check your VS Code settings making sure there are no settings that disable the checking of code.